# Connecting Pi to AVR with both I2C and ISP

Tags: gpio, power, i2c

So I'm attaching an ATTiny85 to a Pi Zero to build a variant of [this WS2812 LED driver](https://www.kreativitaet-trifft-technik.de/project/tiny-ws2812-controller.en.html). The Pi talks to the ATTiny via an I²C/TWI interface.

However, I also want to be able to update the software on the ATTiny. A solution would be to put the chip on a socket and remove it for reprogramming, but hey, it is attached to a Pi already — I guess could use that for over-the-air reprogramming.

From what I see online, I²C traditionally uses (physical) GPIO pins 3 and 5, while ISP uses 19, 21 and 23 (plus any other pin for RESET). So I see (at least) two possibilities here:

1. connect ATTiny pin 5 to both GPIO pins 3 (SDA) and 19 (MOSI), pin 7 to pins 5 (SCL) and 23 (SCK), etc.;
2. connect ATTiny pin 5 to only pin 19 and pin 7 to only pin 23, and tell the Pi software to speak I²C on these two GPIO pins instead of 3,5.

The precautions I need to take are obviously to disable I²C before enabling ISP (and vice-versa); and for the first solution, I would probably need to make extra sure that all pins are turned to input between switching drivers, and probably also add a 200Ω between paired GPIO pins for safety. This makes solution 2 more tempting that solution 1, if configuring both drivers to use the same pins is feasible. Would something like this work?

As a bonus question: I don't need to drive many WS2812 LEDs (certainly < 50), and the power supply that I will use is rated quite above the total current consumption. However, its output is a USB plug, which is convenient to plug directly into the Raspberry (instead of extracting two wires to power the LEDs in parallel to the Raspberry). So: is there a pair of places on the Pi Zero board where I can draw power from, with slightly less limitation than a pair of GPIO pins?

Comment: Have a look at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/ota-updates-for-arduino-using-nrf24l01 - basically write a new boot loader.

Comment: Why not use SPI for both communication and programming? And your last paragraph is a different question which should be asked separately, and with more details (diagram?) to make it answerable.